# Lost on HTML5 database connections

Tags: php, javascript, html, websocket

I am still new in HTML5 and barely starting out. I did HTML for awhile as a module for my school and did a simple "online-shopping" site where I can use JSP files to communicate with my server. However HTML5 is an entirely whole new ball game for me, I hope the Stackoverflow community would be able to help me out with my queries.

So, I did some reading up on websockets however I am really lost in this area. I know what websockets does but I am not entirely sure what it is. For example, in the examples I have read, they only taught me how to create a new websocket object or how to have a connection between this websocket object, and there is supposed to be a url. An example of the code is this,

```
var Socket = new WebSocket(url, [protocal] );
```

So what exactly do I fill in the "url" area? Do I simply put the IP of my server or do I have to direct it to some php or html file, etc? I have downloaded WAMP and I would like to use apache as my server. Is this possible or do I have to use something like node.js? In a way I have no idea what "websocket" really means. Is a "server" or a feature within the "server" or a package which bridges the connection between the server?

And also are there other alternatives to using something similar to JSP in HTML5 for server data storage?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to connect to any database is by using `MySQL` which is a range of functions built into PHP.

Here is a function `database_connect()`

```
public function database_connect($database_location, $database_user, $database_password, $database_name) {
    mysql_connect($database_location, $database_user, $database_password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database_name) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Just paste this function at the top of your page or in an include file, and then connect to your database by calling it in one line:

```
database_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
```

This is the simplest way to connect to an SQL database, I hope this is what you were looking for! Remember that this code is in `PHP`